# the default of attribute in coredata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I did versioning and I added a new attribute of type string

it will be empty at first I want to create a predicate to check for the empty attribute I tried

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                            @"( SeriesStudyID == '""' )"  ]];
```

but it doesn't work

what's the default of this attribute and how to detect the empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeriesStudyID is NSString

if ([SeriesStudyID length]<=0) {

    NSLog(@"empty");
}

else {
    NSLog(@"not empty");
}
```